# Не работает transform.Translate через префаб

Tags: unity3d, transform, prefabs

При загрузке сцены у меня создаётся объект игрока по заранее заготовленному префабу.

Я хочу реализовать перемещение. Первый вариант - я сделал внутри метода FixedUpdate, где отслеживается нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре. - все работает отлично.
Второй вариант - добавил Button и внутри того же скрипта написал функцию Move, которая должна вызываться по нажатию на Button и перемещать персонажа на несколько координат.

Проблема в том, что внутри FixedUpdate - идёт работа с созданным по префабу объектом игрока, в то время, как моя функция Move работает именно с префабом, а не созданным объектом.

Вот два варианта перемещения:

Первый (работающий)

```
private void FixedUpdate () {

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
 { 
transform.Translate(0, speed, 0);
Debug.Log(transform.position.y); 
} 
}
```

Второй (неработающий):

```
public void Move () { 
transform.Translate(0, speed, 0);
Debug.Log(name + transform.position.y); 
}
```

Почему Debug.Log(transform.position.x) в FixedUpdate выводит координаты объекта созданного по префабу, а вызываемая функция public void, в которой находится Debug.Log(transform.position.y) - выводит координаты, указанные в префабе?

Comment: Видимо, `Move()` Вы вызываете у префаба, а `FixedUpdate()` автоматически выполняется у созданного экземпляра.
Покажите код, которым Вы вызываете `Move()` и создаете объект из префаба.

Comment: Move я вызываю таким образом:

Comment: На событие OnClick перетянул префаб, далее выбрал скрипт перемещения, в которой находится функция и выбрал функцию. А создание объекта из префаба находится в другом скрипте с помощью Instantiate